# Newly added Picklist Values not showing up

Tags: dependent-picklist

So I have a picklist on the Opportunity object called 'Loss Reason'. This Loss Reason field is dependent on a controlling field called Stage.

I've added two new values to the Loss Reason picklist but they won't populate when I select an opportunity to test.

Things I've checked:

1. I checked the values were active
2. I ensured the values have been included in all the record types.

I'm not knowledgeable with field dependencies. Is there something I need to do here to get these values to populate on the opportunity object?

Thanks for any help!

[image: Record type with included values]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked if you included these new values in the Field Dependencies?
Go to Field Dependencies> Stage> Edit

[image]

Include the new values over here. And now when you select the appropriate stage which needs to display those values in Loss Reason field, you will see it!

[image]

Let me know if this solution worked!

Comment: Hi, this worked perfectly! Thank you so much :)